# Where to save the Salt string when Encrypting Passwords (Java)?

Tags: java, sql-server, spring-boot, spring-security

I have this approach where I must Encrypt Passwords already saved in clear text on database.
I am going to use **SHA3.Digest256** and a **salt of 20-characters string**.

To obtain an unique password for each user (even for those with the same password) I intend to use a **Random Salt**, my question is: **Is it safe to store this salt on the database?**

The development scenario is **Spring Boot 2.2.2 with SQL Server** database.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Generally, salt is considered safe to be publicly available. As such, you can store it in a separate column in your users table, un-encrypted.